# Confused about model/entity meaning and separation of CRUD and business logic

Tags: php, model, entity, domain-driven-design, laravel-4

I am writing an application where most of the legwork is done in the models, the models perform 2 (fairly distinct) groups of tasks:-

1. CRUD database operations
2. Create `Table`, `Form` and `ContentBox` objects, populated with with data from the database

Some of the models as a result are quite big, so I have setup the [Illuminate Database component](https://github.com/illuminate/database) from the [Laravel framework](http://laravel.com) and I am thinking of using the Eloquent ORM to create models that do the CRUD and then have separate models which generate the Tables and Forms, calling methods in the Eloquent models to get data.

What would be the correct terms for these 2 different 'models' in domain driven design? Do I call the models that do the CRUD **entities** and the other models **models**?

I've read a few of the related posts and I understand a model is a model of something in the real world. So for example I've got a model called `Invoices` which has methods for returning a `Form` object, for creating a new invoice, and a `Table` object, for listing all the invoices. But it also has a method for returning a PDF of a single invoice. So this isn't really a model of a single invoice - it has the ability to return data for multiple invoices... is this still a model?

Apologies there are actually 2 questions here, I'm just wondering what the correct terms are, or looking for suggestions to somewhere I can read about this sort of thing, so that I can do something that is considered best practice and will make sense to other programmers.

Thanks in advance.

**Update** So after reading [this](http://blogsh.de/2011/09/08/models-vs-entities/) it seems to me that what Laravel calls a *model* (before adding business logic to it) is in fact an *entity*. So what I'm planning to do is have a folder called `Entities` with my ORM 'models' in and another folder called `Models` with the business logic 'models' in - is this common practice?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Table or Form are domain models in your case.

Domain models are reflection of your core business concepts. For example, you can answer whether an Invoice is overdue by call invoice.isOverdue()

On the other hand, Table for listing invoices, outport pdfs are responsible for taking care of presentation concerns.

Presetation components have dependence on Domain objects, but not vice versa. For example, you may list Invoices on a html page or outport Invoices by pdf. But you probably don't want the code looks like this:

```
public class Invoice {

    Table list() {...}
    File  outport() {....}
    ...add another method for excel maybe? 
}
```

You may interested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166740/what-are-the-typical-layers-in-an-onion-architecture/18168046#18168046) for the component's responsibilities.

Comment: So maybe I should have several classes such as `InvoiceTables` `InvoiceForms` `InvoiceEntity` and `InvoiceRepository`? Where the entity deals with simple CRUD operations, repository does more complex queries and the Tables and Forms use the Repository to populate Form and Table objects which are then passed to the controller to be thrown into a view?

Comment: @rgvcorley I'm not familiar with php. In java, I use InvoiceRepository to retrieve an Invoice and let it answer some question(e.g. is it overdue or what's the amount due) or store it back to the repository after some updates. Tables and Forms are not necessary in simple projects, but you'll need them if you want to sperate presentation concerns from domain model.

Answer (score 1):

It's common practice to setup what are models in laravel in the Models folder.  I believe what you are looking for are called repositories which you'd make a folder for, and add it to the autoload section in your composer.json file.

It's considered good practice to have lightweight controllers and models aren't really intended to contain all the extra logic, so having repositories where you'd put all the heavy lifting would help keep your app very organized.

Comment: Ok, I've read up a bit more and it seems like Entity should deal with identifiable records, repositories should contain more complicated queries and services then contain business logic which uses the repositories, so the services would be generating my Table etc... objects