# Onion Architecture: Where does Application Layer reside?

Tags: domain-driven-design, onion-architecture

a) If DDD application is implemented using Onion Architecture, would `Application layer` reside within the Onion's `Application Service layer`?

b) In Onion's `Object Services layer` we put interfaces that provide infrastructure behavior ( such as `ISendEmail` or `IRepository` ), but what kind of behavior should interfaces in Onion's `Application Service layer` provide?

Thank you

Comment: Have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166740/what-are-the-typical-layers-in-an-onion-architecture), this should help you out.